# Can I use an expired passport to go home to get my passport renewed?

Tags: passports, kuwait, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian currently working in Kuwait and my passport will expire on March 31, 2015 but my residency will expire in 2016.

I want to go to Ghana in July 2015 to renew my passport, but by then my passport will have expired.

Can I travel with it and get it renewed without any problem?

Comment: why should you go to Ghana to renew your passsport

Comment: What is stopping you renewing your passport before it expires?

Comment: This question should be asked on [the site about living abroad](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), not travel.

Comment: @DJClayworth really? It's not really about where or what he's doing, but about whether or not he can travel on an expired passport to his home country.

Comment: How is this off-topic? The question is about traveling with an expired passport to the country that issued the passport, and not about "immigration or moving for extended periods of time".

Comment: I also agree that this is about traveling and therefore reopened the question.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot travel with an expired passport.  Once a passport expires, it is no longer a valid travel document (even if it contains a valid visa).

As there is no Ghanaian foreign mission in Kuwait, you need to contact the [Ghanaian Embassy in Saudi Arabia](http://www.mofa.gov.sa/sites/mofaen/SaudiMissionsAbroad/ForeignMissions/Africa/Pages/EmbassyID93.aspx) to renew your passport.

Once you have renewed your passport, you need to transfer your Kuwait residency from your old (expired) passport to the new one. This is done at the passports department ("jawazat") for the governorate of your residency.

If you choose not to do this transfer, make sure you carry both your new and old passports with you when you enter into Kuwait. The immigration officer will need to see your old residency page (as the information in the immigration system is linked to the passport number). The officer will then stamp on your old passport, indicating that you need to transfer the residency to your new passport.  Once this stamp is affixed to your old passport, you **must transfer the residency** and will no longer be allowed to travel on your old passport into Kuwait.

Comment: Traveling != Entering. The question is specifically about exiting a third country on an expired passport, and then traveling to the issuing country. In this specific scenario it is not possible as the expired passport will be refused at customs (at least in Kuwait) - if the person is transiting on their flight they might have additional issues.

Comment: Everything is possible, again I don't know the specifics in this case and I can easily believe it would not be possible in Kuwait. But in some countries exiting might also be possible, this was just one example to show that the “rule” is not as absolute as you made it sound.

Comment: From my experience (being specifically stuck with an expired passport) it most definitely is absolute. At least I did not get any special exceptions. Also, specifically for Kuwait it will absolutely :) not work.

Comment: I want to see the very immigration official who won't let through an (unwanted) person willing to leave the foreign country and go back to his home country on an expired passport. It saves them a bunch of bucks compared to putting him in jail and they don't have to pay the extradition ticket. If you have to make a connection, things are different, though. And then there is the case when his passport is checked before he intends to leave.

Comment: The first obstacle would be the airline who will not wish to let you on board.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Personal experience can't logically tell you whether the “rule” is generally true or not. You're the citizen of a specific country (or perhaps two or three) and hopefully were only stuck once, also in a given country. Without getting into other details and complications like transit and the like, that's only one combination from roughly 200 x 200 potential country-citizenship pairs.